# how can i switch from my amd itegrated graphics to my dedicated graphics card (rtx 3060)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I bought a lenovo legion 5 with rtx 3060 and ryzen 5600h and I want to switch from radeon integrated graphics to my 3060

Comment: There are many Nvidia installation answers here.  Some gotchas that might not be mentioned are:Be in Performance power mode, so the default GPU is the Nvidia. Secure boot off is still recommended, but the latest releases seem to work with SB transparently (much to my surprise). Use the standard repos for your Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.